# Separating two lights on one switch

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch

I have 1 light switch that controls a fan/light and a pair of recessed lights across the room. I want to separate them and add another switch next to the existing one. Where do I start?

Comment: Post photos of the boxes, please.  (Just upload them somewhere and post links in comments if you can't get them edited into your post yourself :)

Comment: Close pictures that are nicely in focus are the very best so it is possible to see what is coming into the box in terms of wires and how they are connected to the existing switch.

Answer (score 1):

You start by determining where the circuit is fed.

For example, is it fed from the switch, the fan/light, or one of the recessed lights.

That will determine how you go about adding another switch.